# Is there an alternative to appendRow in AppsScript that only prints certain columns while leaving others in the row untouched

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm building a calculator to use for pricing purposes. It has a primary "Calculator" sheet, where an admin can enter data and then generate a new result to the "DataLog" sheet. The "DataLog" sheet stores the results (columns A through X) and calculates the resulting price (columns Y through AO). There are also a few workflow columns that need to be present for each row (Columns AP through AS).

I am currently using `appendRow()` to print the data to the "DataLog" sheet. The issue is that `appendRow()` finds the first empty row, and since columns Y through AS are not empty because they contain necessary formulas/workflow, it prints to the bottom of the sheet. I am looking for a way to print the data where 1) it checks only a certain column for an empty row (column A or C, for example) and prints to that row, and 2) does not overwrite the formula/workflow columns (Y through AS).

Is there a way to do this using `appendRow()` or is there another function I should be using? Other than this one issue of where to print the results, everything works just as I want it to, but I cannot seem to find a way to resolve this issue.

EDIT: The reason the formula and workflow must be present within "DataLog" is that there are situations where after an entry has been filled out and printed changes need to be made to row, thereby changing the final price. So I cannot calculate the price within the function and print that as a static number.

Here is a copy of the calculator: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vsVZeOUUqhdiW1unz6dPuiP5yw24ENrv1-49kXqBnx4/edit#gid=0

Here is a copy of the code I am using:

```
function ClearCells() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('CALCULATOR');
  sheet.getRange('G9:H9').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('G11').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('G14:H14').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('G6').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('I6').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('I17:I21').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('I24:I29').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('I32').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('K5').clearContent();
  sheet.getRange('K15').clearContent();
}

function FinalizePrice() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  const sourceRangeFL = ss.getRangeByName('FirstLast');
  const sourceValsFL = sourceRangeFL.getValues().flat();
  const sourceRangeEN = ss.getRangeByName('EntityName');
  const sourceValsEN = sourceRangeEN.getValues().flat();
  const sourceRangeEP = ss.getRangeByName('EmailPhone');
  const sourceValsEP = sourceRangeEP.getValues().flat();
  const sourceRangeRT = ss.getRangeByName('ReturnType');
  const sourceValsRT = sourceRangeRT.getValues().flat();
  const sourceRangeRE = ss.getRangeByName('Returning');
  const sourceValsRE = sourceRangeRE.getValues().flat();
  const sourceRangeBQ = ss.getRangeByName('BasicQuestions');
  const sourceValsBQ = sourceRangeBQ.getValues().flat();
  const sourceRangeSEQ = ss.getRangeByName('SchEQuestions');
  const sourceValsSEQ = sourceRangeSEQ.getValues().flat();
  const sourceRangeEQ = ss.getRangeByName('EntityQuestions');
  const sourceValsEQ = sourceRangeEQ.getValues().flat();
  const sourceRangePYP = ss.getRangeByName('PYP');
  const sourceValsPYP = sourceRangePYP.getValues().flat();
  const sourceRangeADJ = ss.getRangeByName('Adjustment')
  const sourceValsADJ = sourceRangeADJ.getValues().flat();
  const sourceRangeAN = ss.getRangeByName('AdjustmentNote')
  const sourceValsAN = sourceRangeAN.getValues().flat();


  

  const sourceVals = [...sourceValsFL, ...sourceValsEN, ...sourceValsEP, ...sourceValsRT, ...sourceValsRE, ...sourceValsBQ, ...sourceValsSEQ, ...sourceValsEQ, ...sourceValsPYP, ...sourceValsADJ, ...sourceValsAN]

  console.log(sourceVals)

  const anyEmptyCell = sourceVals.findIndex(cell => cell === "");
  if(anyEmptyCell !== -1){
    const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
    ui.alert(
      "Input Incomplete",
      "Please enter a value in ALL input cells before submitting",
      ui.ButtonSet.OK
    );
    return;
  }

  const date = new Date();
  const email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

  const data = [date, email, ...sourceVals];

  const destinationSheet = ss.getSheetByName("DataLog");
  destinationSheet.appendRow(data);
  console.log(data);

  sourceRangeFL.clearContent();
  sourceRangeEN.clearContent();
  sourceRangeEP.clearContent();
  sourceRangeRT.clearContent();
  sourceRangeRE.clearContent();
  sourceRangeBQ.clearContent();
  sourceRangeSEQ.clearContent();
  sourceRangeEQ.clearContent();
  sourceRangePYP.clearContent();
  sourceRangeADJ.clearContent();
  sourceRangeAN.clearContent();


  ss.toast("Success: Item added to the Data Log!");

}
```

Comment: You could .getValues() of a certain column that's always filled and do a loop to find the index of the first empty value

Comment: My understanding is that appendRow() itself finds the first empty row, so I would need another way to print my array. From everything I've read, printing is difficult in Google Sheets and that's where I'm stuck - either I use appendRow() and have the problem listed above, or I don't know what to use to get successful results printed into DataLog. Any suggestions, or any way to bypass appendRow() trying to print to the first empty row?

Comment: It's hard to tell what  you wish to do since you are using namedRanges in order to get your data and we have no knowledge of what ranges they actually are.

Comment: Apologies - simply, the input fields on the Calculator tab. So G6, I6, G9, H9, G11, H11, G14, H14, I17:I21, I24:I29, I32, K4, K9, K15, K20, K25. If you need me to change that in the code it is easy to do for the purposes of trying to solve the appendRow() issue

Comment: Your issue boils down to using setValue() in individual locations or grabbing everything that's in the array and replacing the values in the array and then writing the entire array at one time.  There is no way to have setValues skip certain columns of a given row.  It replaces the entire array at one time.  Which is why it is so much faster.  This often does cause problems for those that use cell formulas.  Which is one of the reasons I never use them.

Comment: I think I understand, yet if you are offering a solution I am missing it. If you have a suggestion, can you clarify how it A) prints the results from "Calculator" sheet to "DataLog" sheet, B) doesn't overwrite the entire row and/or doesn't print to the bottom row (row 9000, for example). In the spreadsheet example link, the results I would expect is this was working would populate row 150, columns A through X, without erasing columns Y and beyond

Comment: If you wish to get isolated values I'd recommend the use of a rangeList to collect and print the data

Comment: If you could  inform us as to how you wish to have the values from the source ranges printed I'll do my best to assist you.

Comment: rangeList definitely looks like an improvement. Each cell in Calculator corresponds directly to a column in Datalog. So for example, an input in Calculator G6 would be printed to DataLog column H. Calculator I6 would be printed to DataLog I6. So each input, when the script is run, is essentially cut/paste to DataLog. Does that clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is incomplete but for the purpose of discussion here's how I would clear content in your situation.

```
function ClearCells() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  sh.getRangeList(["G9", "G11", "G14:H14", "G6", "I6", "I17:I21", "I24:I29", "I32", "K5", "K15"]).getRanges().forEach(r => r.clearContent();)
}
```

If you wished to append the values of your individual ranges into a row you could do it like this:

```
function appendRangeValues() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  const rgl = sh.getRangeList(["G9", "G11", "G14:H14", "G6", "I6", "I17:I21", "I24:I29", "I32", "K5", "K15"]);
  const rglb = breakUpRangeList(ss,sh,rgl);
  const vs = rglb.getRanges().map(r => r.getValue());
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs))
  osh.getRange(osh.getLastRow() + 1, 1, 1, vs.length).setValues([vs]);
}
```

But I'm guessing that you want to skip over cell functions and other columns so let me know what you want and may be we can find a solution that fits your needs

The breakUpRangeList function is something I wrote a while back to break up ranges into their individual cells which I find easier to deal with.

```
function breakUpRangeList(ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive(),sh=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0"),rgl) {
  let b = [];
  rgl.getRanges().forEach(rg => {
    rg.getValues().forEach((r,i) => {
    let row = rg.getRow() + i;
    r.forEach((c, j) => {
      let col = rg.getColumn() + j;
      b.push(sh.getRange(row, col).getA1Notation())
    })
  })
})
  b = [...new Set(b)];
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(b));
  return sh.getRangeList(b);
}
```

Try this:

```
function appendRangeValues() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  const osh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1')
  const rgl = sh.getRangeList(["G9", "G11", "G14:H14", "G6", "I6", "I17:I21", "I24:I29", "I32", "K5", "K15"]);
  const rglb = breakUpRangeList(ss,sh,rgl);
  const vs = rglb.getRanges().map(r => r.getValue());
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(vs))
  osh.getRange(getColumnHeight(3,osh,ss) + 1, 1, 1, vs.length).setValues([vs]);
}

function getColumnHeight(col, sh, ss) {
  var ss = ss || SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = sh || ss.getActiveSheet();
  var col = col || sh.getActiveCell().getColumn();
  var rcA = [];
  if (sh.getLastRow()){ rcA = sh.getRange(1, col, sh.getLastRow(), 1).getValues().flat().reverse(); }
  let s = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < rcA.length; i++) {
    if (rcA[i].toString().length == 0) {
      s++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }
  return rcA.length - s;
}
```

Comment: To be specific, the "output" range does not contain formulas nor do any columns need to be skipped. The formula columns that I mentioned all come *after* the printed cells. So when printed, it would print to A through X - no skips, no formulas, just empty space in those columns. But Y and after, which would not be output to, do contain data or formulas. The issue with appendRow is that it sees a value in, say, column Z and therefore skips that row entirely. So instead of printing to row 150, it prints to the bottom of the sheet

Comment: That's good then using the map the way I did in the example might be close to what you desire.  The breakUpRangeList function results in a rangelist of single cells and the Logger.log associated with it will provide a list showing how it has been broken up.

Comment: These are definite improvements! I changed everything, but I am having the same issue where instead of printing to row 150, it is printing to the first row which has no values in any cell. i.e., row 150 is empty from columns A through X, but has a value in column Y and beyond. Row 219 has no values in any column. This script printed to row 219. Is there a way using your script to print to row 150 by checking, say, column C for the next empty cell instead of checking the entire row? If we can get that last bit solved, this works exactly as I want it to

Comment: Added another version that calculates the heigh of column C.  All of these functions depend upon sheet.getLastRow() so if you are use array formulas then none of them will work.

Comment: It's working! Thank you so much, this is working exactly as I intended it to. You have been so helpful, thank you so much