# Script does not clear all checkboxs

Tags: google-apps-script

I wrote a script that removes values from certain ranges and resets checkbox before range if it is preset.

Addresses in cell looks like:
**Page_1!B2:E3;Page_1!B5:E6;Page_1!B8:E9;Page_1!H2:K3;Page_1!H5:K6;Page_1!H8:K9;Page_2!B2:E3;Page_2!B5:E6;Page_2!B8:E9;Page_2!H2:K3;Page_2!H5:K6;Page_2!H8:K9**

Code:

```
const SettingAddress = "B14"

function DeleteCellValues(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var SettingsSH = ss.getSheetByName("Settings");
var AddressesCell = SettingsSH.getRange(SettingAddress).getValue();
var AddressesList = AddressesCell.split(";");

//var CheckboxCell = SettingsSH.getRange(CheckboxAddress).getValue();
//var CheckboxList = CheckboxCell.split(";");

for (var k = 0; k < AddressesList.length; k++) 
  { 
    var CCheckbox = ss.getRange(AddressesList[k]).getCell(1,1).offset(0,-1);
    //SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast(CCheckbox.getA1Notation());
    if (containsCheckbox(CCheckbox.getA1Notation())== true)
    {
      if (CCheckbox.getValue() == true)
      {
        var data = ss.getRange(AddressesList[k]).clearContent();
        CCheckbox.uncheck();         
      }
    }
    else
    {
      var data = ss.getRange(AddressesList[k]).clearContent();
    }
  }  
}

function containsCheckbox(a1Notation){
  var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange(a1Notation);
  var validations = range.getDataValidations();
  return validations[0][0] != null
        && validations[0][0].getCriteriaType() === SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.CHECKBOX;
}
```

For some reason some of the checkboxes doesn't get reset.
When I run script from sheet it works as intended.
I found that it has something to do with declareces with first page and cell or something, but I didn't find how to fix/apply it to my case...

Any idea how to fix it or improve something?

Comment: To help you get a more accurate answer, it would be beneficial if you could provide a minimal, reproducible example, such as a dummy sheet, that demonstrates the issue you're facing along with your desired result. This would allow the community to better understand your problem and provide targeted solutions. Including a reproducible example will greatly increase your chances of receiving a helpful response. [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I see that the expected result is showing up whenever the code you provided is being used. You mentioned in @Cooper's answer that `It works as intedet in a plain sheet, but in my own it doesn't uncheck some of the boxes for some reason.` Would you be able to provide a replication of that?

Comment: Here is the worksheet. Works on the same principle, it just has a lot more things and functions. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11exRvka5vjjOEGTQzTqfRzNy7rPjc-1x--5_JT98I_w/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I did some tests and found that the checkbox function returns false/true depending on first page for some reason ...

Comment: Would you be able to share the spreadsheet you've posted in public? It seems like it's been set to private

Comment: I re-eneble it.

Comment: Thank you for providing access to your spreadsheet. I did some testing with your current code and put the other pages in cell `B14` of the `Settings` sheet and it's unchecking all the checkboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as I said in the comments, the problem was passing the "getA1Notation" value to the function and creating a new sheet instance in the function.

Simply moving the function to the main script now works as intended.

```
const SettingAddress = "B14"   
    
function DeleteCellValues(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var SettingsSH = ss.getSheetByName("Settings");
var AddressesCell = SettingsSH.getRange(SettingAddress).getValue();
var AddressesList = AddressesCell.split(";");
    
for (var k = 0; k < AddressesList.length; k++) 
  { 
    var CCheckbox = ss.getRange(AddressesList[k]).getCell(1,1).offset(0,-1);
    var validations = CCheckbox.getDataValidations();

    if (validations[0][0] != null
        && validations[0][0].getCriteriaType() === SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.CHECKBOX)
    {
      if (CCheckbox.getValue() == true)
      {
        var data = ss.getRange(AddressesList[k]).clearContent();
        CCheckbox.uncheck();         
      }
    }
    else
    {
      var data = ss.getRange(AddressesList[k]).clearContent();
    }
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function getDataRangeSetChkBxsToFalseAndClearContentsOfAllOthers() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const rgA1 = sh.getDataRange().getA1Notation();
  let rgl1 = sh.getRangeList([rgA1]);
  let rgl2 =breakUpRangeList(ss,sh,rgl1);
  rgl2.getRanges().forEach(rg => {
    let rule = rg.getDataValidation()
    if(rule != null && rule.getCriteriaType() == SpreadsheetApp.DataValidationCriteria.CHECKBOX) {
      rg.setValue("FALSE")
    }else {
      rg.clearContent();
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to put an array of strings in the "breakUpRangeList" function - I found your own function in another post.
And I think this sript doesn't check the cell before range.
I have added a link in post to the test sheet . It works as intedet in a plain sheet, but in my own it doesn't uncheck some of the boxes for some reason.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to post that function.

Comment: You can find a copy [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74510667/7215091)